# Namespace Value for updating AIR applications XML Confusion

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, namespaces

I'm confused on the second line here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<update xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/framework/update/description/2.5"> 
   <versionNumber>1.2</versionNumber> 
   <url>http://www.postureviewer.com/update/testAppForUpdating01.air</url>
   <description>This is the latest version of Posture Viewer.</description> 
</update>
```

I'm using AIR 14.0.0.178 but am clueless on the 2.5 at the end of the line. A person would think that that would be 14.0, but that value simply doesn't work. With my test setup to test an update scenerio, 2.5 is the largest value that works. I'm sure 1.0 would work as well, but where does this number come from? Is it related to some script that adobe controls and it's either 1 or 2.5? Does it have anything to do with the version of AIR that I'm using? Does anyone understand what this is or is it so obvious that I'm missing it?

I'm using Flash instead of Flex in case that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format for the update descriptor file changed in 2.5, hence the different namespace there (older versions used "1.0"). I guess since there haven't been any changes to the format of this file since then, there is no need for them to keep updating the namespace with every new version of AIR.

Some more info about the descriptor file here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS3A1F0087-BF77-45ed-B442-E654E5C7E8F1.html